# Need help! What's wrong with my peppers? Brown on underside of leaves

Tags: diseases, pests, peppers

I'm a beginner and this is my first year growing hot peppers. A few of my peppers have started to become brown under the leaves and the plants slowly begin to look sickly. I've looked for similar issues online but I cannot find any answers to this particular problem. It started on one or two pepper plants but it seems to now be affecting more of my pepper plants... It's only appearing underneath the leaves. Two of my plants that are affected by this the most, have now started looking sickly and the new growth has started to die off. I cannot see any bugs on the plants. At first I thought my spray to keep away aphids and mealybugs was the cause (a spray of dish soap and water) but it seems to have now spread to plants that I haven't sprayed yet. It seems to just be affecting my cayenne plants at the moment. Maybe that makes a difference? I bought them all from a nursery. Does anyone have any ideas what this is? I have 20+ pepper plants and 4 are showing signs of this. I'm worried that it will spread to my other plants... I can take more pictures if that will help. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: brown under pepper leaves]